# My tests are failing because of "could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am writing test for the first time. Below is my test.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import PostJobComponent from './postJobComponent';

describe('<postJobComponent />', () => {
    it('title field', () => {
        let wrapper = shallow(<PostJobComponent />);
        const title = wrapper.find('job__title');
        expect(title.props().value).toBe(undefined);
    });
});
```

The PostJobComponent is below.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { postJobAction } from './redux/postJobActions';

const PostJobComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch(); // Here it shows error.

  const onPostJobSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const title = event.target.title.value;

    dispatch(postJobAction({
      title,
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div className='post-job'>
      <form onSubmit={onPostJobSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Job Title</label>
          <input type='text' name='title' className='job__title' placeholder='e.g. Frontend Developer, Project Manager etc.' />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button>Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PostJobComponent;
```

Here is my index.js file where I am adding Provider.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import './index.css';

import App from './container/App';

const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('root'));
```

But I am getting this error in my tests.

```
<postJobComponent /> › title field

    could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

       9 |
      10 | const PostJobComponent = () => {
    > 11 |   const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

What mistake am I doing and how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

When you unit test a component, it isn't rendered into your app, it's rendered in isolation. You need to provide a Redux store for the component when testing, in other words, you need to wrap `PostJobComponent` with a `Provider` component and provide a `store`.

I suspect you could do something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import PostJobComponent from './postJobComponent';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';

const store = configureStore();

describe('<postJobComponent />', () => {
  it('title field', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PostJobComponent />
      </Provider>
    );

    const title = wrapper.find('job__title');
    expect(title.props().value).toBe(undefined);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer above from **Drew Reese** is correct, but just wanted to complement with an idea that we use here in my company. We created a common "mount" function to avoid this boilerplate in every test.

You can put this in a shared file:

```js
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'

export const mountWithStore = (
  component,
  mockState,
  mockDispatch = jest.fn()
) => {
  const mockStore = configureStore([])

  const store = mockStore(mockState)
  store.dispatch = mockDispatch

  return mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
      {component}
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

And use like this in your test:

```js
import {mountWithStore} from './helperFunctions'

describe('<postJobComponent />', () => {
  it('title field', () => {
    let wrapper = mountWithStore(<PostJobComponent />);
    const title = wrapper.find('job__title');
    expect(title.props().value).toBe(undefined);
  });
});
```

Or passing a mock state as a second parameter, to render your component in a specific state:

```js
describe('<postJobComponent />', () => {
  it('title field', () => {
    const mockState = {
      myData: {
        isLoading: true
      }
    }
    let wrapper = mountWithStore(<PostJobComponent />, mockState);
    const title = wrapper.find('job__title');
    expect(title.props().value).toBe(undefined);
  });
});
```

Or even checking that redux dispatchs are called:

```js
describe('<postJobComponent />', () => {
  it('title field', () => {
    const mockState = {
      myData: {
        isLoading: false
      }
    }
    const mockDispatch = jest.fn()
    let wrapper = mountWithStore(<PostJobComponent />, mockState, mockDispatch);
    const button = wrapper.find('button');
    button.simulate('click');
    expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({type: 'LOAD_DATA'})
  });
});
```

The nice thing about this is that you can easily add other things, like a `<Browser>` wrapper (if you use `react-router`), or a `<IntlProvider>` if you have translations, etc.

PS.: This was based on the `react-testing-library` idea. Links [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/kentcdodds/react-testing-library-examples/tree/main/?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2F__tests__%2Freact-redux.js&previewwindow=tests) and [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/).

Comment: +1 For the wrapper pattern and `react-testing-library`. We don't even really use enzyme anymore at our company on my team, RTL is superior in many ways.

Comment: Thanks! It's the same here...I changed my wrapper code to post here as an example, but we also migrated to RTL when enzyme didn't support hooks :)